# Mac OS X no environment variables when using sudo

Tags: bash, macos, environment-variables, nativescript, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to setup a development environment for nativescript on mac os high sierra.

I installed all the require tools (which contains android sdk, jdk). And added a path (ANDROID_HOME, JAVA_HOME) for both of them using .bash_profile, .bash_rc.

If tns doctor which checks if the environment variables are set - It's all good.

But when I run sudo tns doctor, it says ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME and no configured. I thought this may be more of a mac problem than a nativescript problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `sudo -i` which will simulate logging in as root and source the `~/root/.profile`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [man sudo](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html):

> -E
>   The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables. The security policy may return an error if the -E option is specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

If you want variables to preserve it's values, call `sudo -E tns doctor`. You can also call `sudo "ANDROID_HOME=$ANDROID_HOME" "JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" tns doctor` to export only these two variables.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `-E`

```
> export VAR=hello
> sudo su
Password:
> env | grep VAR
> exit
> sudo -E su
> env | grep VAR
VAR=hello
```